# Matplotlib transformation from data coordinates to figure coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code came from the [Matplotlib 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/en-au/product/matplotlib-30-cookbook-9781789135718?type=print&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAlcyuBhBnEiwAOGZ2S5AG1tIdmdDusS18Q4CYS6Cv8c3TLClPdVPEMOz85nEEyw5kpOYxmRoCJLoQAvD_BwE)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128)
y = np.sin(theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(theta, y, 'r-*')

xdata, ydata = 3, 0
xdisplay, ydisplay = ax.transData.transform_point((xdata, ydata))

bbox = dict(boxstyle="round", fc="1.0") # bounding box to be used around the text description
arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="->", color='green', lw=5, 
             connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90,rad=10")
offset = 72 # specify the coordinates where the text description is to be placed on the plot
# Annotation for the point in the data co-ordinate system
data = ax.annotate('data = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (xdata, ydata),
                  (xdata, ydata), xytext=(-2*offset, offset), 
                   textcoords='offset points', bbox=bbox, arrowprops=arrowprops)
# annotation for the point in the display coordinate system
disp = ax.annotate('display = (%.1f, %.1f)' % (xdisplay, ydisplay),
                  (xdisplay, ydisplay), xytext=(0.5*offset, -offset),
                   xycoords='figure pixels', textcoords='offset points',
                   bbox=bbox, arrowprops=arrowprops);
```

The above code is supposed to produce this visual (according to the book)
[image]

However, when I ran that code in Jupyter Lab (3.5.3), it generated this image
[image]

I suspected this was due to this line of code

```
xdisplay, ydisplay = ax.transData.transform_point((xdata, ydata))
```

Which yielded different values compared to those shown in the book's visual (which were 214.5, 144.7)

[image]

Could someone please explain what had gone wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also ran a similar [tutorial code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html) provided by `matplotlib` using VS Code, and the outcome wasn't correct either. Was this because my laptop's display or the code didn't consider/take into account the differences in users' hardware?

[image]

Comment: I guess you took it from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html). I run the code they provide with Matplotlib 3.8.0 and it produced the same figure as they claim. I was not using Jupyter.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, @Maciek. Based on your info, I ran the tutorial code on VS Code but the display was still misaligned as shown in the edit of my OP.

Comment: Have you tried running it out of Jupyter?

Comment: I did. The second graph (in the edited post) was produced from VS Code.